# How do I use wildcards in REST AP /_api/web/Lists/getbytitle?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to retrieve all lists from the SharePoint site that start with "ABC".

This doesn't work

```
https://......sharepoint.com/sites/...../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ABC*')/items
```

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to filter the contents of a list, rather, I am trying to filter the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do want to filter a list! The list of all lists.

The `getbytitle()` endpoint is just for getting a specific list, and AFAIK can't be used like what you are asking.

Fortunately with a lot of REST calls you can just trim the url to a higher endpoint...

```
https://......sharepoint.com/sites/...../_api/web/lists
```

That endpoint returns all the lists in the site. You could then add `?$filter=startswith(Title,'ABC')`. There is also `substringof()` which isn't quite a wildcard, but can be useful.

I don't know of any way to get all the items from those lists in one call, unless you want to use the search rest api.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.